# OpenGrok on Windows - svn history not enabled

Tags: batch-file, tomcat, svn, opengrok

I setup OpenGrok on a Windows Server 2012R2, and trying to index an SVN repository that resides on the same server.

I managed to have the source indexed and OpenGrok basically working but history/annotate features are not enabled.

I followed those steps:

I made a working copy on the same machine and the run the indexing with these lines

```
set PATH=C:\the\path\to\svn\executable;%PATH%
REM my repo requires authentication, so I added this vars
set OPENGROK_SUBVERSION_USERNAME=user
set OPENGROK_SUBVERSION_PASSWORD=pwd
java -jar lib\opengrok.jar -W .\configuration.xml -c C:\path\of\ctags.exe -P -S -v -r on -s C:\path\of\src -d .\grokdata
```

By doing this I cannot see any meaningful info on opengrok.log, only this suspicious line:

```
...done scanning for repositories (0s) --> it seems too fast
```

Then I run tomcat, also ensuring to have SVN on the PATH and the variables for authentication

```
set PATH=C:\the\path\to\svn\executable;%PATH%
set OPENGROK_SUBVERSION_USERNAME=user
set OPENGROK_SUBVERSION_PASSWORD=pwd 
%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\startup.bat
```

**BUT history/annotate features are not enabled**

---

My setup: Opengrok 1.0 - Subversion 1.9.2 - Apache Tomcat 8.5.30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to use the "-H" option:

```
-H
    Generate history cache for all repositories
```

To see all option execute:

```
java -jar lib\opengrok.jar
```